# Get Checkbox status

Tags: custom-form

I'm trying to prevent users from editing an item after i've set a "WIP cutoff". I have a checkbox to set this and I'm trying to get the status of that checkbox using a function that has been used extensively in an existing customised sharepoint 2007 site. The Function is:

```
function getField(fieldType,fieldTitle) { 
    var docTags = document.getElementsByTagName(fieldType); 
    for (var i=0; i < docTags.length; i++) { 
        if (docTags[i].title == fieldTitle) { 
            return docTags[i] 
        } 
    } 
}
```

So in order to get the "Checked Status" of the box:

```
<input name="ctl00$m$g_0c239981_ad37_4fda_8a14_7015542b4518$ff113_1$ctl00$ctl00$BooleanField" title="WIP Closed Off" id="ctl00_m_g_0c239981_ad37_4fda_8a14_7015542b4518_ff113_1_ctl00_ctl00_BooleanField" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" value="on"/>
```

I'm using with the help of share points built-in "PreSaveAction" function [so I've been told]:

```
// PreSaves Edit WIP NEW
function PreSaveAction() {
    if (getField('input', 'WIP Closed Off').CHECKED == "checked") {
        alert("This Campaign has been closed, you can not edit products.");
        //return false;
        history.go(-1);
    }
}
```

I originally thought that I should be getting the "Value" of the checkbox but it is alway ON regardless of the checkbox state.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the DOM will hold the *checked* property as [lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473562/javascript-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-being-checked-or-unchecked), so you should be fine by doing:

```
if (getField('input', 'WIP Closed Off').checked) {...}
```

Make sure that getField actually return the element you seek.
Another approach is to use jQuery, like this:

```
if (!$('[title=WIP Closed Off]').prop('checked'))) return;
```

Comment: maybe slightly out of context, but after jquery introduced .prop it's better to use that for this kind of case, like - if (!$('[title=WIP Closed Off]').prop('checked')), anyway performance is same, just another approach

Comment: Good call, updating answer. Also, in theory it might actually be faster for those that care, there are some [tests as well](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/7). I do find .is to be readable though, and it's even 1 char shorter :D

Comment: Hi Eirikb, thanks for the tip, the checked property was indeed lowercase, so I've gotten a step closer. Unfortunately Jquery is a bit beyond me at this stage. So I've got this bit of code now: `code`function PreSaveAction() {alert(getField('input', 'WIP Closed Off').checked); if (getField('input', 'WIP Closed Off').checked == "true") {alert("This Campaign has been closed, you can not edit products."); history.go(-1);}`code` The first alert returns "true", however the if statement doesn't happen–the record gets saved. I've tried doing additional OR statements for "on" and "checked" but nothing.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, but in any case, by using the first line of code I gave you it should work fine. It does not weakly compare the boolean value `true` to the string `'true'`, as `true == 'true'` is false.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/08/20/a-dummies-guide-to-sharepoint-and-jqueryndashgetting-amp-setting-sharepoint.aspx this may help

Comment: hi  eirikb, can you tell, whether can I use that line of code within the PreSaveAction function call ? Because ` if (!$('[title=WIP Closed Off]').prop('checked'))) return;` will be written within code block of the document.ready(function ... ) .So where to write the above `LOC` .

Comment: @SaMolPPp why would you need `document.ready`? It's not like the form isn't done loading when the users tries to save

Comment: Somehow my code with the same line,as you mentioned, is not working when I put within the presaveaction call.That's why I asked.So ,as per your suggestion I can very well use the if($('[title=wip closed off]').prop('checked')) should work & fetch the value.Right?

Comment: @SaMolPPp Yes, given that the selector is correct

Comment: if i uncheck the already checked checkbox,and click on save button, am unable to capture the values.Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Comment: @SaMolPPp by capture do you mean inside `PreSaveAction`? This comment section is getting out of hands, perhaps you could start a chat?

Comment: capture means, accessing/fetching the value from the  checkbox fields and  textboxfields.Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

True is not a string! In both cases where I was checking to see if checked was "checked" or "true" I was calling it as a string with the double quotes. I removed the quotes and the if statement worked.

Rookie mistake!